# properties are not being loaded from application.yaml

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have a JUnit test that requires `MyUtilityClass` to use properties from `src/main/resources/application.yaml` file that is inside resources directory in my SpringBoot application, but JUnit is unable to load properties and I am getting null value when I call `response.getValue()`. So, what could be wrong in my code?

**MyUtilityClassTest**

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@TestProperties(location="classpath:application.yaml")
public class MyUtilityClassTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private MyUtilityClass muc;

    @Test
    void test() {
        var response = muc.getData();
        assertEquals("EXPECTED_VALUE", response.getValue());
    }
}
```

**MyUtilityClass**

```
public MyUtilityClass {
    
    //this value is loaded from src/main/resources/application.yaml
    @Value("${value}")
    private String value;

    public DataClass getData() {
        var data = DataClass.builder().build();
        data.setValue("Example");
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: To enable Spring Boot features such as [externalized configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config) in your test, your test class must be annotated with [@SpringBootTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications).

Comment: And your ```MyUtilityClass``` should have an annotation like ```@Service``` ...

Comment: `MyUtilityClass`  should register as a bean in the spring context, so annotate it with `@component` or `@service`.